# Закрытие программы по закрытию модальной формы Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Создана модальная форма:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Panel1.Hide;
 GetName := TGetName.Create(Self);
 GetName.ShowModal;
end;
```

После открытия `Form1`, `GetName` успешно закрывается командой `GetName.Close;`.
Как закрыть всю программу если пользователь передумал вводить имя в `GetName` и решил закрыть программу, путем нажатия на крестик?

Answer (score 3):

Надо использовать ModalResult:

```
if GetName.ShowModal <> mrOK then
    Form1.Close;
```

В форме ввода имени следует прописать `ModalResult := mrOk` либо назначить свойство ModalResult соответствующей кнопке.

Comment: в этом случае открывается (повторно) форма GetName

Comment: Ну первый ShowModal-то сотрите.